# Insert ng-repeat list of values to text area, textAngular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, textangular

I'm trying to paste list of values to text area with using textAngular directive and faced with the problem, that I cannot do that. For some reason it shows me just brackets without any errors in console.

The only one way how I can paste data to textAngular is provide path such as:

`comparesing[0].description` directly in ng-model of textAngular, but I need to display list of values. So could anybody help me to find my mistake? thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
 angular.module("textAngularTest", ['textAngular'])
    .controller('wysiwygeditor', ['$scope', 'textAngularManager', function wysiwygeditor($scope, textAngularManager) {
        (function () {

          $scope.data = '[{"id":11820,"occuredDate":"2016-10-26T18:23:01.000Z","title":"Log In","description":"User 123-001 logged in"},{"id":11819,"occuredDate":"2016-10-19T18:32:07.000Z","title":"Log out","description":"User has logged off"}]'

          $scope.comparesing = JSON.parse($scope.data)

          $scope.orightml = '<ol ng-repeat="(key, value) in comparesing"><li>{{value.description}}</li></ol>';
        }());
    }]);
```

html

```
       <div text-angular name="Narrate items" ng-model="orightml"></div>
```

[this is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBY11KipDrHEsJxPsBOp?p=preview) with my error

Comment: textAngular doesn't parse the **data** stored in `ng-model` and evaluate it as **code**;  what you are trying to do isn't possible with this plugin, as far as I know.

Comment: @Claies yes it does the parsing. I tried `$scope.orightml = "<ol><li>abc</li><li>def</li></ol>";` and it parsed it

Comment: explained another way: you can't have a model (`comparesing`) defined inside another model (`orightml`).   What you pasted in the comments is plain HTML, not angular expressions.

Comment: @Claies so Is there any way to parse, list of values to text area?

Comment: @Claies You're right.

Comment: you could build an HTML string in the controller by using `$compile`, but the resultant string will be static HTML with no contextual binding back to the object it was built from;  changes in the text window won't change the underlying object, or the server side data.  This isn't a plugin that can be used as a data mill.